# Connect to Remote AWS MySQL from GoDaddy via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm having an issue connecting to a remote MySQL server that is hosted by Amazon Web Services. I can connect to this MySQL server from virtually any other computer, but for some reason I cannot get it to be pulled into my PHP that is hosted on GoDaddy.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$cxn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbname)
         or die("Query died: Cannot connect.");
```

I've added the host name for the MySQL server into GoDaddy's CPANEL > Remote MySQL Access Hosts. I know that the variables are correct, because I've tested this on another server and everything works fine.

I've been on the phone with GoDaddy twice now, and all they've said is to try asking a forum (apart from adding the MySQL host to the Remote Access Hosts page).

I've checked the security group for the AWS MySQL and made sure that it is open to the GoDaddy's hosted IP address...

I'm just not sure what else to do! Why isn't this working on GoDaddy's server when it was working just fine on another??

MySQL v5.6 --> on AWS
PHP v5.4 --> on GoDaddy

Comment: It's a really, really bad idea to have your PHP on GoDaddy and your DB on AWS. Latency will kill your site with any significant amount of queries on a page.

Comment: The CPANEL thing is where you tell GoDaddy what external machines may access your GoDaddy-hosted MySQL databases. But you're trying to access an external MySQL host from GoDaddy.  It seems likely to me that GoDaddy has a data-center-wide firewall blocking outbound requests on port 3306, MySQL's port. I bet GoDaddy's frontline support people don't have a clue about that kind of thing; you'll need to escalate your ticket to network operations if you can persuade them to do it.

Comment: What is the value returned by `mysql_error()` when the connect request fails? How long does the connect request take before it fails (does it time out, or is the connect request rejected by the far end machine)?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I didn't know that about the CPanel. I'll check out to see if there is a firewall.     As for @ceejayoz comment, I have an entire VPC that is doing much heftier queries to/from the MySQL in AWS. I'm performing very light queries from GoDaddy, so it makes sense in our situation to have the setup like this.

Comment: @OllieJones it times out, but it takes a very long time to do so. That's what is making me think it is some sort of a firewall somewhere...If it was just bad variables, it would err out pretty fast. But it takes about 30 to 60 seconds to timeout and then kicks back that it couldn't connect.

Comment: The weird thing is it doesn't return any error message. Just dies after about 30 seconds...

Comment: Thanks for the help @OllieJones! I'll have to speak with GoDaddy again and see if they can escalate my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the the information in the question and the comments, it is clear that GoDaddy's network operations team does not allow outgoing TCP connection requests on port 3306 (that's MySQL's default port).

That means you can't originate a connection from a program running on a GoDaddy server to a MySQL server located elsewhere. If you do, it will stall until the TCP connection timeout elapses.

What can you do about this?

1. Ask them to allow your outgoing 3306 traffic.  (Not likely, I suspect. Their business model doesn't afford much per-customer network engineering work.)
2. Try getting your MySQL server to listen on some other port, perhaps 8000. 8080, or another of the commonly used "alternative" http ports. Those might not be blocked. Then use

   mysql_connect("$host:$port",$user,$passwd,$dbname)

to connect.

You'll need to look up how to get an AWS-resident MySQL server to listen on a nonstandard port.

Comment: Thanks for the great information, @Ollie Jones! After a lot of effort, I tried to reconfigure the AWS-resident MySQL server to listen on a different port, but couldn't waste any more time. Instead, I decided to just split my database in half and the website relevant portions on the GoDaddy CPANEL. Seems like GoDaddy is pretty adamant about having all of your systems with them—they don't like to play well with others. Anyway, as soon as the GoDaddy hosting contract is up, I'll probably just host the site on an EC2 server.